# Avoid duplicate content with rel=canonical

Tags: canonical-url, rel-canonical

I have multiples pages that refer to the pretty similar content and I decided to set the `rel="canonical"` tag to let Google know what is the actual original content. I'm not sure though whether I'm proceeding correctly in this case.

The scenario is that I have beach pages that may appear on multiple location pages. Say for example that I have `www.example.com/location-a/beach-a` and because `beach-a` is also part of location-b I do also have the URL `www.example.com/location-b/beach-a`. Obviously the main content is the same but things like breadcrumbs, meta description or titles may be different.

Am I right in saying on `www.example.com/location-b/beach-a` that "the canonical URL" should be `www.example.com/location-a/beach-a` or should they exist as separate URLs? I don't know how to tell Google that type of relationship between the two locations sharing the same beach if that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can, move stuff from `www.example.com/location-b/beach-a` to `www.example.com/beach-a`.

Like this you won't have to deal with this issue, and you will give more "power" to one page instead of spreading it on 2 pages.

Comment: That makes sense. What if I want or need to have both location-a and location-b URLs?

Comment: @CarlosTorrecillas I believe what Stephen is saying here is that you should have location pages and beach pages. Each are canonical. On the location pages if you feature cards in a "nearby beaches" section that includes the same title and description of the beach pages it won't be duplicate content.

Comment: @Mike Ciffone, that makes sense. I'll do that, thanks!